# Using SQL Server local temporary table with MyBatis

Tags: sql-server, mybatis

In MS SQL Server, the local temporary table is prefixed with a # in the table name.

```
select * from #foo
```

But MyBatis uses # for specifying placeholders.

How can I use SQL Server's local temporary table with MyBatis?

I tried various possible escape methods, but none of them worked.

Comment: The problem was not about placeholder escaping, it was that the create table statement was called in the stored procedure, so that it could not be referenced from subsecuent SQL. It solved by directly executing create table from jdbc.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for one of the following approach for fixing your problem.

> 1- Go for a stored procedure, in the stored procedure you can do what ever you want.
>
> 2- Use @Table instead of #Table (If your data is not huge and you don't need feature like index creation/trunation etc)

Comment: " Use @Table instead of #Table" - just be aware can have side effects....

Comment: @MitchWheat I agree with you, I have updated the response :)